# How to draw a "Perfect Shape" on MFC c++?

Tags: mfc

I'm working on a small project on MFC where i'm building a mini paint.

i was wondering if its possible to draw a perfect circle and a perfect square using the Rectangle and Ellipse function.

Perfect shape as holding the Shift button in paint.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. What is your question?

Comment: i can't figure it out  how to make it equal.

Comment: The easiest approach would be to call [CDC::SetMapMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class#setmapmode) passing the `MM_ISOTROPIC` value. This ensures that 1 logical unit along the x-axis is equal to 1 unit along the y-axis.

Comment: You need to ensure that x and y are equal when the Shift button is pressed. What is the question? Totally unclear.